# How can i connect between Snowflake and IoT Sitewise to share data?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, iot, snowflake-connector

I am looking for any connector or any other ways that i  can connect and get data from snowflake to  IoT Sitewise.

Answer (score 1):

The ways of connecting to Snowflake are all documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/conns-drivers.html